# how to loop audio to a ffmpeg generated video

Tags: ffmpeg

i am a beginner programmmer and am trying to implement ffmpeg. I am trying to convert a bunch of images to video and add a audio background. Can anybody help me and tell me how to loop the audio as required by the length of the video generated.

PS. This number of images varies so can we implement something that dynamically loops the audio as required

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i images%d.jpg -f lavfi -i amovie=audio.mp3:loop=0,asetpts=N/SR/TB -shortest out.mp4
```

Comment: thank you for your response, it is highly appreciated

Comment: I now have to create transition in the images like fade in - fade out . The code that i am currently running is: "ffmpeg  -framerate 1/5 -start_number 100 -i #{temp_dest_folder}/image%03d.jpg -f lavfi -i amovie=#{audio}:loop=0,asetpts=N/SR/TB -shortest -c:v libx264 -r 30 -pix_fmt yuv420p -s 640x360 -strict -2 #{output}" how would I do that. Any help would be highly appreciated